# What is the meaning of "would be" in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> I would say it depends of the compressed archive to be honest. Some executable can be archive that needs to be decompressed, and they can also execute an executable after. An example of this **would be** drivers you download from manufacturer's website. HP and Dell for example, offers drivers under the form of an .exe, that when execute will extract itself in another location (like C:\Dell\Drivers\FOLDER) and once extracted, it'll execute the .exe inside it that launches the drivers installation. So if you were to come across a such executable, then yes executing it and "extracting" it could lead to an infection assuming that the executable file executed after the extraction is malicious.

Is it a conditional statement? The meaning is ambiguous to me, can you please explain it in the context provided? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Substitute '***is***', for '*would be*': *An example of this **would be** drivers you download from manufacturer's website*.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning here of "An example would be..." is essentially identical to "An example is...".

There is an implied conditional: the implicit idea expressed more fully is "If you were to ask me for an example, I would say..."

(You can find other examples of this usage of "would" on this site discussing, for example, the slight differences between "I think..." and "I would think...".)

If the meaning is effectively identical, you might well wonder what is the point in complicating the sentence by saying "would be" instead of "is". It could be considered an example of hedging (additional words added to soften the directness of what is being said) or because the speaker thinks it sounds more learned.